# The embed that shows the list of youtube videos shows up but the embed for the chosen video doesn't (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, audio-player

I'm very very new to javascript but always wanted to learn it so here I am.

I was making a discord music bot and already managed to integrate the youtube-search module into the bot. I followed some guides on how to make an embedded message to show the list of videos that the bot can stream and wanted to make the same for when the user chooses a video, but the embedded message for that never shows up. No errors seem to show up in the console.

Here's the user input part:

```
filter = m => (m.author.id === message.author.id) && m.content >= 1 && m.content <= ytResult.length;
let collected = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { maxMatches: 1 });
let selected = ytResult[collected.first().content - 1];

    embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${selected.title}`)    
        .setURL(`${selected.link}`)
        .setDescription(`${selected.description}`)
        .setThumbnail(`${selected.thumbnails.default.url}`);

message.channel.send(embed);
```

I have defined `embed` further up as:

```
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle('Test title')
     .setDescription('Test Desc');
 let embedMsg = await message.channel.send(embed);
```

I've only been writing javascript for a few days but really want to get better at it and make this damned bot.

Comment: You're creating two new objects take out let embed stuff up top and just define the embed as you create it

Comment: I realized the embed might not be the problem. I think it might be the code for the user input part, but I still don't understand what's wrong with it. It seems to work when inputting a keyword to search on youtube but then doesn't work when inputting the number of the video on the list.